# Renaming classes generated by Entity Framework for Code First development

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework for the first time. I'm using Code First development with an existing database. Everything is working great but I do not like using the table name as the class name. The database tables do not making for friendly class names in C#. Is it common place that people rename the classes that are auto-generated by EF? Will this cause problems down the line in some capacity that I am not anticipating? FWIW, I'm not worried about future schema changes to the tables.

I Google'd a few times but no one seems to have asked this before. Maybe I should take that as a sign....

Answer (score 8):

You can use either [data annotation attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx):

```
[Table("tblFoo")]
public class YourEntity
{
}
```

Or [fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()  
    .ToTable("tblFoo");
```

to provide table name which entity maps to.